# Monetbil with php api is not working

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I need to use monetbil payment gateway for one of my project which is in underdevelopment.

I have created account using the below url

https://www.monetbil.com/operators

I have created service using my account and monetbil support has approved it.

I read the documents which is provided by monetbil from the below url,

```
https://www.monetbil.com/docs/monetbil-payment-widget-v2.1-en.pdf
```

and made a demo.

in response they returned me success as well as the payment url

while I click on the payment url,it was asking contact number.

I am from India so that I gave a invalid number.

Please any one tell me if any dummy number is available for testing?

I searched for developer account but I didn't find anything.

If there is any developer account please let me know.

or can we use it for india ,becuase while I am creating account it gives me option to select country.

but while I am creating service it not gives me option to select coutry .It allow me to select cameroon only.

Comment: First off, this sounds like a question you should ask monetbil. Second why can't you just use your indian number?

Comment: I compulsory asked me for mobile number with +237 initial ,it will not allow Indian number.I have also email to support team and waiting for their reply

Comment: you are right it's support team is really good they help me to resolve my problem.there is no sendbox account.but they provide me dummy contact number with minimum balance for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to enter that number for which country you are implementing the functionality ask for your client and enter number and do payment. but i think so you have to use test keys for this purpose.